# How to overlay audio tag inside a td tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I'm trying to overlay an html audio tag, but i could not found a way to do it, even if i set z-index the audio player stay always on the top , is there any way to overlay it ?

```
#overlay {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

 <td class="overlay" onclick="alert('test');">
 <a > 
  <audio controls id="audio" preload="all" autoplay > 
  </audio> 
 </a>
</td>
```

Comment: You're using a class, so the selector should be `.overlay`. But that doesn't fix your issue. I'm not sure why the `<audio>` element doesn't seem to respond to `z-index`. Maybe because it "has no intrinsic visual output of its own unless the controls attribute is specified, in which case the browser's default controls are shown" ([audio @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)). If you just want the `click` event to work, try adding [`pointer-events: none;`](https://jsfiddle.net/qo61dezg/) to the `<audio>` element. Maybe someone else will have more insight.

Comment: Thank you so much, all the hustle that i was doing is to trigger click event, you have solved my issue!

Comment: Cool! I'm still curious about the layering issue. I hope someone more knowledgeable chimes in.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors, I have done a snippet with the errors corrected.

But, above all , the is no sense in wrapping the audio in a table if at the end yopu set position absolute on it , it seems that your approach is somehow useless.

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td class="overlay" onclick="alert('test');">
      <a>
        <audio controls id="audio" preload="all" autoplay> 
  </audio>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>last</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts, but i couldn't see which error you talking about!